Error in compiling QGroundControl Windows, QGC v4.2 I followed the build instructions too
01:07:30: Starting C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\AxQt\qgc\Stable_V4.2\build\Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Release\staging\QGroundControl.exe...
Settings location "C:/Users/Imran/AppData/Roaming/QGroundControl.org/QGroundControl Daily.ini" Is writable?: true
Filter rules "*Log.debug=false\nGStreamerAPILog.debug=true\nqt.qml.connections=false"
System reported locale: QLocale(English, Latin, India) ; Name "en_IN" ; Preffered (used in maps):  "en-US"
LocalizationLog: Error loading source localization for "en_IN"
LocalizationLog: Error loading json localization for "en_IN"
MAVLinkLogManagerLog: MAVLink logs directory: "C:/Users/Imran/Documents/QGroundControl Daily/Logs"
Map Cache in: "C:/Users/Imran/AppData/Local/cache/QGCMapCache300" / "qgcMapCache.db"
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/MainRootWindow.qml:10:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick": Cannot load library C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\AxQt\qgc\Stable_V4.2\build\Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Release\staging\QtQuick.2\qtquick2plugin.dll: Unknown error 0x000000c1.
"v4.4.3"

I have an issue making MSVC-64 2019 working.
I tried MSVC-64 2015 also but it doesn't work at all, I followed the instructions very well, like downloading additional libraries such as Qt Charts.
I also cloned QGC stable v4.2 properly, then running the recursive command too.
I don't know what happens: the application runs, but the window doesn't appear at all, and I can't see the icon in the taskbar either.

When looking at the error message code: https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0x000000c1  the second reason seems to explain this. The ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT means you are likely trying to use a 32 bit dll in a 64 bit program.
